# Deserializing a large block blob using MemoryStream

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, memorystream, binaryformatter

I need to deserialize large files downloaded from Azure Blob Storage.

**Would using a `MemoryStream` in this fashion be the most optimal way to deserialize the file into an `object`?**

My main concern here is RAM usage.

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    blob.DownloadToStream(stream);
    stream.Position = 0;
    return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

Another option would be to download the entire file as a byte array. Note that this files could be up to 50mb in size.

**EDIT:**

Further from Guillaume's answer:

Would then this then be more optimal when serializing and uploading?

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var stream = blob.OpenWrite())
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, value);
    blob.UploadFromStream(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`CloudBlockBlob.OpenRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.openread.aspx) method to reduce memory pressure.

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (var stream = blob.OpenRead())
{
    return formatter.Deserialize(stream);
}
```

With a `MemoryStream`, you download the whole file (50mb) in memory and I guess the internal buffer of the `MemoryStream` will take 64mb. So downloading it to a byte array can use less memory as the array capacity match its length.
Using `OpenRead` you avoid copying the whole file in memory before processing it. It'll only take the size of an internal buffer that is reused as the file is downloaded.

---

To upload, you can use `OpenWrite` or `UploadFromStream`, don't use both ! `OpenWrite` will need less memory.

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var stream = blob.OpenWrite())
{
    formatter.Serialize(stream, value);
}
```

Comment: Great answer - thank you.  Please see my question regarding the contra - serializing and uploading.